# How to buy multiple Lion licenses from the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I need to install Mac OS X 10.7 Lion on about 10 company workstations.

If those were my personal computers, I could simply buy one license and then log into the Mac App Store on each workstation to download the installer.

But since according to the EULA I need to purchase 10 licenses, I wonder how to do that using a single Mac App Store account (Apple ID)? Is it at all possible to buy multiple licenses for an app on the Mac App Store?

Comment: It's not yet clear what the correct path is to me. I know several schools that have set up multiple accounts to do iOS purchasing - but only used a subset of those accounts to provision devices. The how is simple, the legality or intent of Apple isn't yet clear. Have you reached out to Apple? The online store offers pre-sales chat and phone support if you don't have a better resource locally http://www.apple.com/business/mac/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple Software Volume Licensing](http://www.apple.com/mac/volume-licensing/) lets you purchase bundles of 20+ licenses for Apple software, including Lion. The licenses can be bought via the [Apple Store for Business](http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313) and redeemed in the Mac App Store.

If you need to purchase less than 20 commercial licenses, it seems you cannot do so using a single Apple ID. Have fun creating an Apple ID for each license you want to buy..

Comment: Not actually the case. There is no minimum for purchasing for businesses, it's just not considered a volume license and is a different part number:
http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/product/D6377Z/A

Answer (score 2):

### [App Store Volume Purchasing for Business](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/)

Comment: This is only available in the US at the moment, and requires a DUNS number. Would be great to find out how this would work for smaller companies without DUNS numbers, or companies overseas.

Comment: The App Store Volume Purchasing Program for Business seems to be for iOS apps only, as far as I can tell from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the Mac App Store, no. Just purchasing the licenses at Apple's Online Store for Business, yes:
http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/product/D6377Z/A